# I want to make a tableView method static

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I am currently writing a small application that involves a tableView and an array of ManagedObjects for persistent storage.

What I want to do delete all the ManagedObjects in the array by clicking a button in another view controller.

To do this, I tried to make the array a static variable, unfortunately this conflicts with the methods that I use to populate the table with data from this array. Frustrating stuff.

Here is the code for the class:

```
class ClassOverviewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    static var subjects = [NSManagedObject]()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return subjects.count
    }

    static func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
            let subject = subjects[indexPath.row]

            cell!.textLabel!.text = subject.valueForKey("subjectName") as? String

            return cell!
    }

    static func clearSubjects() {
        for item in (self.subjects)
        {
            CalculateClass.managedContext.deleteObject(item)
        }
        do {
            try CalculateClass.managedContext.save()
        }
        catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

I have removed functions from the class that I did not think were necessary to show you.

It does not like me making the second tableView method static because I have taken that method from UITableViewDataSource.

I am unsure how I am supposed to proceed. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the non-static implementation so your table works.

When you want to remove the objects either:

- get a reference to your `ClassOverviewController` object and call its method
- or, if there's no connection between controllers, use a notification that tells the `ClassOverviewController` object that it should reset its array.